# How to generate a RSA key in Android similar to an OpenSSL PEM_write_PUBKEY generated key

Tags: android, openssl, rsa, public-key

I have a C application, within this application I generate a RSA key pair with the following code (error checking left due to readability):

```
void generateKeyPair(char* pass) {
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
    RSA* r;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    RAND_load_file("/dev/urandom", 1024);

    r = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);

    pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, r);

    FILE* fp = fopen("private.key", "w");
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, pkey, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, 0, NULL, pass);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("public.key", "w");
    PEM_write_PUBKEY(fp, pkey);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I synchronize the public PEM keys through a server between the devices. Now I have to write a compatible Android application though I have to generate the public key in the same format then PEM_write_PUBKEY does.

I know that I should have done the synchronisation in DER format or something but now I can't change the design any more. There is no way around generating the keys in the similar format.

I guess that it is a #PCKS1 base64 encoded key but I am not sure and I don't know how to generate a similar one in Android - Androids standard is #PCKS8. However I would prefer not to include spongy castle in my project if there is a way around.

Comment: PKCS#8 is for private keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck; it seems you only have to PEM encode your public key as both Java and OpenSSL use the same `SubjectPublicKey` structure used for X5.09 certificates. You can get to this by running `RSAPublicKey.encode()`.

Unfortunately I don't know any other library that performs PEM encoding, but I'm sure you can strip out the code from Bouncy or Spongy if required; the Bouncy Castle libraries have a very liberal licensing structure.